# Service Bus for Windows Server - Deferred messages with TTL behavior

Tags: servicebus, ttl, azure-servicebus-queues, dead-letter, azure-pack

When using **deferred messages** the **time-to-live** is being ignored, is it possible to have this behavior and send the messages to **dead letter queues**?

If so, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those looking into the same scenario - **Using TTL on defered messages are not possible as of this writing.**